# Which 'Xbox One X enhanced' game is this city from?

Tags: xbox-one, game-identification

I found a list of games from Microsoft which are [supposed to be better on the X-Box One X](https://www.xbox.com/de-DE/games/xbox-one/xbox-one-x-enhanced-list). In this list was the following picture:

[image: city]

I wonder if this is a real screenshot of a game. I assume so because the other images on the site are from games, too. It looks a bit like Cyrodiil's Imperial City (unless there are no mountains), maybe someone can identify this nice city.

Which game is this city from?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It mentions Middle Earth and [Shadow of War](https://www.xbox.com/en-US/games/middle-earth-shadow-of-war) is in the enhanced list so it must be that.

Comment: Yup, this is it. Image in OP's question is shown on [trueachievements](https://www.trueachievements.com/game/Middle-earth-Shadow-of-War/screenshots) list of screenshots